# When inheriting from public interface, why it doesn't matter if the implementation is public or private?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I might be very well just tired or too long far from C++ but this one really surprised me today:

```
#include <iostream>

class Interface
{
public:
    virtual int aa() const = 0;
    virtual int bb() const = 0;
};

class Usage : public Interface
{
private:
    virtual int aa() const
    {
        int a = 10 * 10;
        return a;
    }

    virtual int bb() const
    {
        int b = 20 * 20;
        return b;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Interface* i = new Usage();
    std::cout << i->bb() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'd expect compiler and/or linker would complain about either bad function signature or at least about missing implementation. Considering this is working and ok, what is the meaning of public/protected/private modifiers when it's hidden by the top class declaration?

How does this rule call in C++ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is specified in paragraph 11.6.1 of the standard:

> The access rules (clause 11) for a
>   virtual function are determined by its
>   declaration and are not affected by
>   the rules for a function that later
>   overrides it. [*Example - basically same as yours*]
>   Access is checked at the call point
>   using the type of the expression used
>   to denote the object for which the
>   member function is called . The access
>   of the member function in the class in
>   which it was defined is in general not
>   known.

Comment: Ha, that's it, you got me. Perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Interface* i = new Usage();
std::cout << i->bb() << std::endl;
```

This is working because the function name is resolved based on the `static` type of the object.

Here the object is `i` whose  `static` type is `Interface*` which has a `public` function name `bb()`. Hence, the compiler doesn't see any problem, as the requirement to call a member function meets it.

Also note that accessibilities (`public`, `private` and `protected`) are compile-time constructs. At runtime, there is no such thing. Compiler can detect any violation of rules related to accessibility at compile time only. It cannot know what happens at runtime.

So even if `i` points to an object whose type is `Usage` which has defined `bb()` in the `private` section, the compiler is fine with it, as noted before the `static` type of `i` is still `Interface*` which has a `public` function `bb()`. The compiler doens't bother with the *dynamic* type of object and how it overrides the function, because it cannot, precisely for the reason that its *dynamic*; its determined at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

`private` means you can't inherit from it. `protected` or `public` you can inherit from but there is nothing stopping you limiting the visibility to a lower level (i.e. `public` to `protected` or `private`; or `protected` to `private`) in your top class.